# Be sure to [Verb] Vs Make sure to [Verb]

Tags: word-usage

Which one is more widely used in native english environment ? Is there any different meaning between these two sentences ?

Be sure to turn off the lamp before you sleep.

Make sure to turn off the lamp before you sleep.

Comment: "Put off" means to postpone. How does one postpone a lamp?

Comment: Unless the *to* there is not *that* (*be sure that* and *make sure that*, they are simply interchangeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say "be sure to turn off the light" or "make sure you turn off the light" interchangeably, with a slight preference for the second form. I think "make sure to turn off the light" is okay grammatically. It's just less common.

[This answer on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121442) has some good, objective information about the relative frequency of the different phrases that's consistent with my first reaction.